# Ansible ssh connection drops [fails] for one of the task while works for other tasks

Tags: ssh, ansible, connection, connectivity

Here is my playbook having three tasks:

```
- name: Play 2- Configure Source nodes
  hosts: all_hosts

  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=8 -o ServerAliveInterval=50
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /app/misc_automation/ssh_keys/id_rsa

  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

   - name: Get Process Dump for tomcat on non-Solaris
     ignore_errors: yes
     block:
       - raw: ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep
         ignore_errors: yes
         register: tomjavadump

       - raw: ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep | wc -l
         ignore_errors: yes
         register: tomjavadumpcount

       - raw: "echo <tr><td>{{ inventory_hostname }}</td><</tr>"
         delegate_to: localhost
         when: tomjavadump.rc == 0 and patchthistomcat is undefined
```

I ran the above playbook in debug mode and the exact same ssh connection works for the two tasks but fails for the first task as seen in the debug output below:

```
TASK [raw] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/Ansible/playbook/check.yml:1260
<10.0.0.211> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.0.0.211> SSH: EXEC ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/misc_automation/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=8 -o ServerAliveInterval=50 10.0.0.211 'ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep'
<10.0.0.211> (1, '', '')
<10.0.0.211> Failed to connect to the host via ssh:
fatal: [10.0.0.211]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
...ignoring

TASK [raw] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/Ansible/playbook/check.yml:1267
<10.0.0.211> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.0.0.211> SSH: EXEC ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/misc_automation/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=8 -o ServerAliveInterval=50 10.0.0.211 'ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep | wc -l'
<10.0.0.211> (0, '0\n', '')
changed: [10.0.0.211] => {
    "changed": true,
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "0\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "0"
    ]
}

TASK [raw] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/Ansible/playbook/check.yml:1270
skipping: [10.0.0.211] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skipped": true,
```

I have no idea but the same code works fine if i change the target server from 10.0.0.211 to something else.

Why does the exact same ssh connection work for other tasks and fail for the first task ?

How can I fix this issue ?

Here is the maximum debug for ssh failed and passed connections for both the failing and passing tasks https://filebin.net/8v5xy28edtaz0bhh/ansible_ssh_issue.txt?t=o4l9o4d1.

Comment: change `raw: ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep` to `raw: ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep||true` in  your first task.

Comment: With `|| true` the task shows ssh connection successful but i do not want to add `|| true` Instead i want to record `tomjavadump.rc != 0` but becoz of the failed ssh I'm not getting the value for `rc`. Please suggest.

Comment: problem is `ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep` in your remote node is returning non zero and `raw` module would fail it as connection failure. you cannot depent on  `rc` of `raw` module. you need to think of an alternate way to check the rc.

Comment: suggestion: remove `||true` and instead add `|awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print "rc="rc}'` and later search `'rc=0' in tomjavadump.stdout`

Comment: `ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep` fails and i expect rc to be non-zero i.e  unsuccessful. But, adding `ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep | awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print "rc="rc}'` give me rc value as zero. My guess is because appending `awk` will always return zero i.e success. Kindly suggest ?

Comment: @P.... `ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep; awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print "rc="rc}'` works and i get rc=1. Thank you for the help. I still believe the `raw` module ssh should not have failed as the connectivity is definately there. Although the result rc should have been non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `raw` module, which is running your shell commands inside the remote node which presumably does not have python installed over it.

This means ansible is running your commands as below:

```
ssh user@ip "commands"
```

In your case:

```
<10.0.0.211> SSH: EXEC ssh -o 'IdentityFile="/app/misc_automation/ssh_keys/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=8 -o ServerAliveInterval=50 10.0.0.211 'ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep'
```

And throw the error if ssh fail OR rc of `commands` is non-zero.

To preserve the return code of your command and also prevent `rc` to turn non-zero, you should use

```
-raw: ps -ef | grep java | grep -i tomcat | grep -v grep; awk -vrc=$? 'BEGIN{print "rc="rc}'
```

By doing this you are capturing the `rc` of last `grep` command and printing it via `awk` command. Here `awk` would always return `zero-rc`.

Once you have stdout captured, you can search for `rc=0` or  `rc=1` based on your requirement in the `var.stdout`.

If you do not care of `rc` then just add the suffix of `||true` to your command.